# IndexError: 'list index out of range'

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter

I am running this code.

```
import tweetstream
import csv

twitterUsername = "USERNAME"
twitterPassword = "PASSWORD"

twitterWordFilter = [] #Defined the list
wordListCsv = csv.reader(open('wordstofilter.csv', 'rb'))
for row in wordListCsv:
    #Add the 0th column of the current row to the list
    twitterWordFilter.append(row[0])

print "Filtering the following words: ",', '.join(twitterWordFilter)

try:
    with tweetstream.FilterStream(twitterUsername, twitterPassword,track=twitterWordFilter) as stream:
        for tweet in stream:
            try:
                print stream.count,"(",stream.rate,"tweets/sec). ",tweet['user']['screen_name'],':', tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')
                #print tweet #Use for raw output
            except:
                print "ERROR: Presumably missing field"

except tweetstream.ConnectionError, e:
    print "Disconnected from twitter. Reason:", e.reason
```

When I am debugging it, it gives the following error at line  `twitterWordFilter.append(row[0])`:

```
Error : IndexError: 'list index out of range'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means `row` is empty.

Comment: please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

<<< Original code

```
wordListCsv = csv.reader(open('wordstofilter.csv', 'rb'))
for row in wordListCsv:
        #Add the 0th column of the current row to the list
    twitterWordFilter.append(row[0])
```

Original code>>>

Here,

Your CSV file is empty, thus it returns an `[]` (empty list) to `wordListCsv`

```
twitterWordFilter.append(row[0])
```

and you are trying to access an element which is no longer existing...

Answer (score 0):

```
wordListCsv = csv.reader(open('wordstofilter.csv', 'rt'))
for row in wordListCsv:
```

CSV files are **text** and need to be opened as such.